# Is there any reason to set an exception's cause to itself?

Tags: java, exception

I've come across some places in java libraries that I'm building against where the cause of an exception is set to the exception itself.

Is there any reason for the exception to reference itself as its cause?

**EDIT**

As requested, here is a concrete example:

[image]

Comment: Bad coding practice, if the exception is the cause already, it doesn't have to define a parent cause.

Comment: Sure ... if you *want* to create a circular dependency from which there is no escape. I'm somehow thinking the code isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Also bad practice, but it may happen that a code catches Exception X, and throws a new Exception X, with the old one as the cause. So they may look similar, but actually different exceptions.

Comment: When I've seen this, Eclipse shows the same object reference for both `ex` and `ex.getCause()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's just bad design.  If the exception is the root cause, it doesn't need to define a cause.

An exception that has a cause is a legit case for different exception wrappings.  For example, if creating a persistence store, you might want to throw a PersistenceExcpetion.  So then if it's a file store, you can have the cause be an IOException.  If it's a database, maybe the cause is a SqlException.  Etc

Comment: In fact the casue is not set to itself. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35230848/4494577) to [Why property ''cause" of Exception is repeating forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230698/why-property-cause-of-exception-is-repeating-forever)

Answer (score 24):

I have frequently seen exceptions thrown by frameworks or libraries such as Hibernate or Spring reference themselves as the cause (confusing the debugger GUI in the process).

I always wondered why they did this since it seems like such a bad idea. And today it actually caused a problem when I was trying to serialize one to JSON : bam, enless cycle.

So I investigated it a bit further :

In the source code of `Throwable` (all source code listed here is from JDK 1.7) we have this :

```
 /**
     * The throwable that caused this throwable to get thrown, or null if this
     * throwable was not caused by another throwable, or if the causative
     * throwable is unknown.  If this field is equal to this throwable itself,
     * it indicates that the cause of this throwable has not yet been
     * initialized.
     *
     * @serial
     * @since 1.4
     */
    private Throwable cause = this;
```

Now I specifically met the problem with an exception class that extended `RuntimeException`, so I went from there. One of the constructors of `RuntimeException` :

```
/** Constructs a new runtime exception with the specified detail message.
     * The cause is not initialized, and may subsequently be initialized by a
     * call to {@link #initCause}.
     *
     * @param   message   the detail message. The detail message is saved for
     *          later retrieval by the {@link #getMessage()} method.
     */
    public RuntimeException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
```

Constructor of `Exception` called by the above:

```
 /**
     * Constructs a new exception with the specified detail message.  The
     * cause is not initialized, and may subsequently be initialized by
     * a call to {@link #initCause}.
     *
     * @param   message   the detail message. The detail message is saved for
     *          later retrieval by the {@link #getMessage()} method.
     */
    public Exception(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
```

Constructor of `Throwable` called by the above :

```
/**
     * Constructs a new throwable with the specified detail message.  The
     * cause is not initialized, and may subsequently be initialized by
     * a call to {@link #initCause}.
     *
     * <p>The {@link #fillInStackTrace()} method is called to initialize
     * the stack trace data in the newly created throwable.
     *
     * @param   message   the detail message. The detail message is saved for
     *          later retrieval by the {@link #getMessage()} method.
     */
public Throwable(String message) {
    fillInStackTrace();
    detailMessage = message;
}
```

`fillInStackTrace` is a native method and desn't seem to modify the cause field.

So as you can see, unless the `initCause` method is called subsequently, the `cause` field is never changed from the original value of `this`.

Conclusion : if you create a new `Exception` (or one of the many many subclasses that exist in the wild and don't override this behaviour) using a constructor that doesn't take a `cause` argument, and you don't call the `initCause` method, the cause of the exception will be itself !

So I guess that should make it a very common occurrence.

Comment: You can indeed create an self-causing exception just doing `Exception ex = new RuntimeException("ex");` But the `ex.equals(ex.getCause())` will still return `false` because of the `Throwable` implementation: `return this.cause == this?null:this.cause;`

Comment: true, but also look at Throwable.getCause() {return this.cause == this ? null : this.cause;}, and since cause is private it shouldn't bother you, the only value you'll see is what you get with getCause() and it's going to be null. If you look at exceptions in an IDE, that's another issue, but there it shouldn't be a problem either

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer is misleading, and the other answers are incomplete. So...

While it *would* be bad design to pass in an exception as its own cause, it's not possible in the Throwable implementation for exactly that reason. The cause is either passed in during construction, or else to the initCause() method, and as pointed out in the second answer, the latter would lead to an IllegalArgumentException.

As the third answer points out, if you don't provide a cause, the cause will be *this* as per the Throwable implementation.

What's maybe missing (given the original question) is that the getCause() method of Throwable doesn't ever return *this*, it returns null if cause == this. So although your debugger is showing the *this* reference as the cause because it is using reflection, when using the public interface of Throwable you won't see it and so it won't be a problem.

Comment: Maybe you should re-edit your answer, because I have no idea which one is "accepted" answer, which one is "second", "third" now.

Answer (score 4):

From the sources of `Throwable` I have here:

```
public synchronized Throwable initCause(Throwable cause) {
    ...
    if (cause == this)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Self-causation not permitted");
    ...
}
```

I don't see how setting cause to itself is possible at all.

Comment: IIRC, when I've seen this it has been in specific exceptions from the ORM layer.  There's no reason to believe that because `Throwable` disallows it in the `initCause` method the exceptions I've seen behave the same way.

Comment: See Pierre Henry's answer to see how it's possible.