# Why property ''cause" of Exception is repeating forever?

Tags: java, spring, exception

While debugging with eclipse IDE an HttpClientErrorException I noticed that property "cause" contains a reference to the error itself, so I went through and there it was the property "cause" again, and again ... forever.

Why this property contains a reference to itself?

[image: cause]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Throwable` declares

```
private Throwable cause = this;
```

If the cause is not initialized, either by passing a cause in the constructor or by calling `initCause`, it will continue to point to `this`. Note that consequently `getCause` is implemented as:

```
public synchronized Throwable getCause() {
    return (cause==this ? null : cause);
}
```

**Update:**

The reason for this design is also explained in `Throwable`:

> To allow Throwable objects to be made immutable and safely reused by
>   the JVM, such as OutOfMemoryErrors, fields of Throwable that are
>   writable in response to user actions, cause, stackTrace, and
>   suppressedExceptions obey the following protocol:
>
> 1) The fields are initialized to a non-null sentinel value which
>   indicates the value has logically not been set.
>
> 2) Writing a null to the field indicates further writes are forbidden
>
> 3) The sentinel value may be replaced with another non-null value.
>
> For example, implementations of the HotSpot JVM have preallocated
>   OutOfMemoryError objects to provide for better diagnosability of that
>   situation.  These objects are created without calling the constructor
>   for that class and the fields in question are initialized to null.  To
>   support this capability, any new fields added to Throwable that
>   require being initialized to a non-null value require a coordinated
>   JVM change.

Comment: Thanks. What I found in the doc: "If this field is equal to this throwable itself, it indicates that the cause of this throwable has not yet been initialized."

Comment: @mrMonoProgrammer yes. You can initialize it by passing a Throwable in the constructor, or by calling `initCause`. If this is not done, it will point to this. Also `Throwable.getCause()` observes that fact.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to source where this `Exception` was created?

Looks like the `HttpClientErrorException` object was created and then its `cause` field was modified to be the same object, perhaps using `initCause`.